# How many creatures does Heavenly Fire target?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The [Sorcerer](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/classes/sorcerer.html) Celestial Bloodline has this power:

> *Heavenly Fire (Sp):* Starting at 1st level, you can unleash a ray of heavenly fire as a standard action, targeting **any foe** within 30
>   feet as a ranged touch attack. Against evil creatures, this ray deals
>   1d4 points of damage + 1 for every two sorcerer levels you possess.
>   This damage is divine and not subject to energy resistance or
>   immunity. This ray heals good creatures of 1d4 points of damage + 1
>   for every two sorcerer levels you possess. A good creature cannot
>   benefit from your heavenly fire more than once per day. Neutral
>   creatures are neither harmed nor healed by this effect. You can use
>   this ability a number of times per day equal to 3 + your Charisma
>   modifier.

(emphasis mine)

Does this:

- target any (and every) foe within 30ft of the caster?
- target a single nominated foe within 30ft?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The effect is **a** ray (as in *one single ray*), thus it can only hit a single target at a time.

While I agree that a text worded that way would otherwise be unclear, showing no effort to prevent the confusion (and the books are full of those unclear passages), in this case **any** means *any one* for sure.